# How to do linear regression with the x series being a date in tensor flow?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, linear-regression, tensorflow.js

I am entering the world of machine learning with tensor flow js mostly to try and get some prediction data for charts. I have done the example for a basic sequential model to predict the times table which seems to work well however maybe naively thought you could apply the same basic model to a set of dates.

So for example

```
const model = tf.sequential()

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [1] }))
model.compile({ loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.0001) })

// Convert date strings to time as it doesn't like strings
const inputs = ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05'].map(x => parseISO(x).getTime())
// Values for each date
const outputs = [2, 4, 5, 8, 10]

const xs = tf.tensor2d(inputs, [inputs.length, 1])
const ys = tf.tensor2d(outputs, [outputs.length, 1])

await model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 200 })

// Try make a single prediction for the next day
const predictions = [
  parseISO('2023-01-06').getTime(),
]

model.predict(tf.tensor2d(predictions, [predictions.length, 1])).toString()
```

However the above just gives me `[[NaN],]`

Is there something I am missing here, probably a very obvious an basic error such as maybe using epochs being the issue? As switching the dates back to simple numbers of 1,2,3,4,5 and predicting 6 gives `[[8.9031172],]` which while not accurate could be an expected answer even if it should be guessing a cumulative value.

Just trying to work out where I am going wrong here, any pointers appreciated!

Ultimately the end goal is to try and predict a cumulative value for future dates.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using tf string functions to get your dates into the right data types so that they can be encoded in the computation graph. If you create an end to end reproducible code block I can try and help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did have a look into these methods but they didn't seem suited towards the solution. I may have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this it seems you need either a move complex model suited for time series data or you need to normalise the dates.

So for the above the solution which isn't amazing but works is to set a `day zero` then each subsequent day in the training data is +1 day.

This then means you can predict x days into the future by using a date diff function between day zero and the predicted date.

I still didn't solve the fact the prediction will give a value lower than the previous value which shouldn't be possible as it is a cumulative prediction but that is a separate issue.